# How are schamata represented in Cognitive Load Theory

Tags: cognitive-modeling, cognitive-load

I come across papers that say things like "if the new information is compatible with the schema, it is accepted".  I'm not clear on how schemata are represented by theorists in order to make this claim.  For instance, what does "compatible" mean?  What are the processes that are modeled by theorists that begin with "new information" and end with "accepted"?

Comment: I think this has something to do with language. Take the [Bransford & Johnson experiment](https://scienceblogs.com/mixingmemory/2007/11/30/my-favorite-experiments-bransf): without knowing the topic, the text didn't make sense and the participants couldn't remember much of it. Now, the topic, which is introduced later, is a new piece of information, and it is accepted because it connects to the schema that the text created. But what does "connect"/"compatible" mean? I think it can be studied in cognitive linguistics ([frame semantic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zx0ZrOKQwK4) to be specific).